Issues with SeleniumBase Script – Intermittent Failures Despite Page Consistency
I'm using Selenium to scrape service reading data from the Servipag website with a script that retries up to 5 times in case of errors. The page structure hasn't changed, and this function was previously working reliably. However, I'm now experiencing intermittent failures. Despite successful attempts in the past, the script often fails to locate elements or times out unexpectedly.
Here’s the main structure of my function:
def scrape_servipag_service_reading(service_type, company, identifier, companyType, propertyId):
max_attempts = 5
for attempt in range(1, max_attempts + 1):
    driver = None
    try:
        # Access the page
        driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=True)
        driver.get(f"https://portal.servipag.com/paymentexpress/category/{service_type}")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

        # Select company and enter identifier
        select_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "card-lib-selectCompany-change")))
        Select(select_element).select_by_visible_text(company)
        input_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "card-lib-identifier-change")))
        input_element.send_keys(identifier)
        
        # Click button and wait for results
        button_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "card-lib-btnContinue-click")))
        button_element.click()

        # Fetch results or detect no-debt message
        result_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.form-control.border-primary.d-flex.justify-content-end.align-items-center")))

        # Processing results here...

    except TimeoutException as e:
        logger.error(f"TimeoutException on attempt {attempt}: {e}")

    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        logger.error(f"NoSuchElementException on attempt {attempt}: {e}")

    finally:
        if driver:
            driver.quit()

return None

scrape_servipag_service_reading('agua', 'Aguas Andinas', '2803495-4','agua','asdadsad')

Problem: Despite several attempts, the script frequently fails on specific elements like card-lib-selectCompany-change and card-lib-identifier-change. I’ve tried extending the wait times and ensuring no page structure changes have occurred.
Environment:

SeleniumBase Driver is used with uc=True, headless=True.
Python's logging module is implemented for error tracking.
This function runs on a Windows server with stable internet.

Questions:

Could there be any known issues with Selenium or SeleniumBase
causing intermittent failures in element detection?
Are there any specific techniques to improve reliability for elements on pages that sometimes take longer to load?
Could these intermittent issues be related to the website’s server or response time, and are there ways to handle such cases better?


Have you tried running it without headless, so you can inspect what the browser actually loads in the UI?

Yes, it doesnt work and all loads ok. Before it work ok headless True and False.

Please describe more specifically what fails - what are you expecting, what happens instead, and what do you expect the issue to be if you say the page does in fact load entirely in the browser when not running headless? If the elements are there and they have the attributes you're looking for, they will be accessible - the issue then likely is with the actual processing code that you didn't include.

It fails when the script tries to locate the select element with select_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "card-lib-selectCompany-change"))). I expect the script to find this element and proceed, but instead, the driver closes because it can't locate the element. The webpage visually appears fully loaded, so I suspect that the scraper might be detected. This could explain why the element isn’t accessible even though it should be present on the page.

Instead of assuming "it should be present on the page", I would recommend pausing execution of your script before that line with the debugger, and open the Developer tools in the driven browser. You can check the element is actually there from the console, and perhaps come up with a more reliable way to detect it if it is, but it's not quite as you expected.
